# Trying to get flattened data out of map()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to create an object to be used in a JSON request, based on the controls on the page and their values.

I'm using the jQuery `map()` function to get the keys and values out of the controls like so

```
var data = $("fieldset > div.section").map(function (i, e) {
    var result = {};
    result[e.children[0].id.substring(3);] = e.children[1].value;

    return result;
}).get();
```

This gets the data I'm after, but I end up with nested objects rather than an array, this looks like so

```
[{"ClientId":"123456"},{"ClientIdType":"5"},{"City":"Brisbane"},{"Sex":"10"},{"PostCode":"4064"},{"State":"QLD"}]
```

But what I want is something like

```
{"ClientId":"123456","ClientIdType":"5","City":"Brisbane","Sex":"10","PostCode":"4064","State":"QLD"}
```

Is there a way to do this in one go, or should I just iterate over the array again to flatten it?

Comment: After `substring` do you have that semicolon? I wouldn't expect it to work if you did.

Comment: If you want it in one go then you will need to declare the result before map and inside map add the values to the result object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case for `each()` not `map()`:

```
var data = {};

$("fieldset > div.section").each(function (i, e) {
    data[e.children[0].id.substring(3)] = e.children[1].value;
});
```

Comment: Indeed, since jQuery doesn't provide `$.reduce()` for some reason, `each` is going to be your best bed.